# CSS Selecting Issue

Tags: css, hover

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H91pk.png)I'm just trying Hover Effect in CSS but I'm having a problem when I select an item in another container

Well, it's like this

when I checked w3schools and there is plenty of selectors, I found them not to match with I'm trying to do
so 65% I'm wrong with something in CSS or HTML hierarchy
[image explain the situation]

Comment: Make sure to add the code into the question not a photo https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: GIven your current HTML structure you cannot do this with pure CSS - CSS won't 'go back up' see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors?msclkid=97c4eb76b31211ec9578d84c59bb34a8

Comment: @Mehrwarz this will not work -  .colored-area.one does not select anything.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/Montinyek/ybtLg2w9/1/

```
.color1:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).